# Weka copy filter does not work

Tags: weka

I am trying to get the first column of a dataset using weka. But Copy filter returns the whole set! why? Thanks.

```
Copy mCopy = new Copy();
mCopy.setInputFormat(rawData);
String rangeList;
rangeList = "first";
mCopy.setAttributeIndices(rangeList);
Instances dataSlice = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter( rawData, mCopy);
System.out.println(dataSlice);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your code works well, it will add another copy of the `first` attribute instead of only keeping it, which means `dataSlice` will be `rawData + first attribute of rawData`.
- Let's correct your code. `setAttributeIndices()` should be invoked before `setInputFormat()`. This is clearly stated in weka API:

  > Note: use this method before you call setInputFormat(Instances), since the output format is determined in that method.

  If you change the order of calling them, your code will get the result that I said above.
- If you want to keep only the `first` attribute, you may use `Remove` filter and `setAttributeIndices("2-last")`. I'm not skilled in Weka. There may be better ways of doing this.

Hope this could help you.